# Connect to MongoDB Atlas with mongo_dart

Tags: mongodb, dart, connection, mongo-dart

I try to connect to a MongoDB Atlas database through mongo_dart with this line of code. The provided link from MongoDB is defined by:

```
mongodb+srv://<user>:<PASSWORD>@test-asdf.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true
```

throws an "Invalid scheme" Error. When I cut out "+srv" and try to connect with:

```
Db db = new Db("mongodb://<user>:<password>@test-asdf.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true");
```

it throws a SocketException: Failed host lookup.

Is it even possible to access to a atlas mongoDB or am I forgetting something?

Comment: Anything on this yet? Were you able to find a valid way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The **mongodb+srv://** protocol is for new driver, maybe you can try to click the button "I am using driver 3.4 or earlier" to get the legacy url with **mongodb://** protocol

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect to atlas, you need to pass connection string which connect your atlas to mongo_dart like this:

```
import "package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart;

  void getConnection() async {
     String connectionString = "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@test-asdf.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
        print(connectionString);
        // Connect to database:
        Db db = await Db.create(connectionString);
        await db.open();
        print(db);

  
}
```